# WP caching plugins are preventing cookie from being set

Tags: php, wordpress

I made a simple WordPress plugin, it works perfectly fine on my own server, but not on the live website of a friend.

It is a very basic Referral plugin, I used cookie to save the referrer ID, then used `user_register` hook to save it in database after some one signs up.

This is the part that saves the Referrer ID:

```
function set_referrer_cookie() {
    setcookie("referrer_id", $_GET['ref'], time()+3600, "/");
}

add_action('init', 'set_referrer_cookie');
```

The cookie is not set many times, at first I was puzzled, but after a lot of testing, I believe this is caused because of caching (he has a lot of plugins, such as Breeze caching etc)

How can I make sure, the cookie is set all the time?

Is there any way around this?

### Edit:

After running each URL in the browser, the plugin saves a new .php file in its `/breeze/cache/` folder,

I think it is the Output of the PHP file, as the `echo` value is shown in plain text in it, and it's all HTML,

so it appears the Breeze plugin caches the output of PHP in a file, and serves it again as a static HTML, with no option to exclude set_cookie in the admin panel... **is there any way to work around this?**

Comment: Just want to confirm - how do you check if the cookie exist or not? (Using the developers tools?). Check those caching plugins settings -  if there's any option regarding cookies and disable it. I don't think that the caching plugin prevent the cookie as it doesn't make sense as for why

Comment: @OfirBaruch in Developer Tools > Storage, cookie is set sometimes, but mostly it is not (I clear the cookie and trying again), I'm also very puzzled by this and not sure if it is the Caching plugin, the code is very simple, yet the cookie is not set most of the times :( been stuck at it for 3-4 days

Comment: and "$_GET['ref']" is always set? Can you replace it with "demo" (dummy text) just for testing purpose?

Comment: @OfirBaruch I just tried, when I use https://example.com/?ref=17 , the 17 is set in both cookie and $_GET['ref'] echoes to screen, but if I delete the cookie and open the page again, `cookie is not set`, while 17 (echo of $_GET['ref']) still appears on the page, until I change to ?ref=18, then both cookie is set and echo $_GET changes to 18

Comment: @OfirBaruch After running each file, the plugin saves a new .php file in its `/breeze/cache/` folder, I think it is the Output of the actual PHP file, as the `echo` value is plain text in it, and no PHP functions at all, so it appears the plugin caches the output of PHP in a file, and serves it again as a static HTML, with no option to exclude set_cookie in the admin panel... is there any way to work around this?

Comment: If you disable the plugin (just for a test), what would happen?